# Reuse variables and model encapsulated in class

Tags: python, oop, tensorflow, dry

I want to train a model in tensorflow and only define the graph and variables once. So I encapsulated that in a class as follows in this functionally non-sense minimum example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


class Model:
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights", (10, 1))
    bias = tf.get_variable("bias", 1)

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (100, 10), "x")
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, 100, "y")

    output = tf.matmul(x, weights) + bias
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(output - y))
    optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.5, 0.9).minimize(cost)

    def train(self, data, lbls):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            for i in range(10):
                _ = sess.run(self.optimizer, {self.x: data, self.y: lbls})

    def predict(self, data):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            return sess.run(self.output, {self.x: data})


data = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 10))
lbls = np.random.randint(0, 1, (100, ))
mdl = Model()
mdl.train(data, lbls)
mdl.predict(data)
```

I expect the predict function to reuse the trained variables `self.weights` and `self.bias` but all I get is `FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value bias` in the return line of the `Model.predict()` function.

This sounds simple to me, but somewhere I must have a wrong assumption. The [official Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#sharing_variables) just states "Explicitly passing tf.Variable objects around" as one way of sharing variables. Defining variables as class variables should do that in my understanding. I have googled extensively but cannot find a simple example of tensorflow with classes like this. 
In my actual project I fiddled around with variable scope (`tf.variable_scope(.., reuse=True)`) which still raises me an uninitialized variables warning, which I can only fix by initializing but then the trained variables are reset, of course.

Is the whole class approach like this wrong? How can I simply reuse my variables without a saver or other more complicated structure? And: Where is my understanding of tensorflow variables, graphs and so on, wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should use `saver` to save the model then load it but a workaround would be to save the tensorflow session as a variable too and use that for both train and prediction.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Model:
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights", (10, 1))
    bias = tf.get_variable("bias", 1)

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (100, 10), "x")
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, 100, "y")

    output = tf.matmul(x, weights) + bias
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(output - y))
    optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.5, 0.9).minimize(cost)
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    def train(self, data, lbls):
        for i in range(10):
            _ = self.sess.run(self.optimizer, {self.x: data, self.y: lbls})

    def predict(self, data):
        return self.sess.run(self.output, {self.x: data})


data = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 10))
lbls = np.random.randint(0, 1, (100, ))
mdl = Model()
mdl.train(data, lbls)
mdl.predict(data)
```